# Sorting collection using OrderBy not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to sort my collection using lambda according to (in this case "Amount") but also tried other fields. when I output the collection using foreach it is not sorted according to the field

```
Accounts? ac = await Client.SendRequest<Accounts>(tk.access_token, Method.GET, "/UploadedAccounts", "");
                ac.value.OrderBy(x => x.Amount);
                ac.value.RemoveAll(x => x.Year.ToString() != YearBox.Text);

 foreach (var a in ac.value) {
                    ListViewBox.Items.Add(a.CompanyLegalName + " / " + a.Year + "-" + a.Month + " / " + a.AccountName + " / " + a.AccountCode + " / " + a.AccountType + " / " + a.Amount + " / " + a.Dimension , 0);
                }
```

I have also tried to do the sorting after the 'RemoveAll'
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Enumerable.Orderby` is non-mutational; it returns a new `IEnumerable`, which you are currently discarding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.OrderBy(x => x.Amount)` sorts the collection and **returns sorted `Accounts`**. You need to do `foreach` on the list which is return by `.OrderBy(x => x.Amount)`

Like,

```
foreach (var a in ac.value.OrderBy(x => x.Amount)) 
{
     ListViewBox.Items.Add(a.CompanyLegalName + " / " + a.Year + "-" + a.Month + " / " + a.AccountName + " / " + a.AccountCode + " / " + a.AccountType + " / " + a.Amount + " / " + a.Dimension , 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `OrderBy` LINQ extension is returning sorted enumerable. It is not modifying the original collection.